# Is this kitten a boy or a girl?

Tags: cats

I recently rescued a kitten, and I’m having trouble telling whether it is a boy or a girl. Please help! (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kimv.jpg)
[image: ## Heading ##]

Comment: http://medipet.blogspot.com/2007/10/how-to-tell-sex-of-your-kitten.html

Comment: Boy. 100% certain.